# LessCss calling extend from mixin, bug?

Tags: less

If I call:

```
.somemethod({
        &:extend(.flex all);
});
```

then it appears as if less do not complain but it does generate the appropiate css either.

Is this a bug ? Has it been resolved? I am still on 2014 Java version of less, might need an update if it's worth it.

**Edit, added the method somemethod:**

```
.somemethod(@mx){
        @mx();
}

.flex {
        color:blue;
}

body > main {
   .somemethod({
          &:extend(.flex all);
   });
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for `.somemethod` mixin (the actual implementation) and `,flex`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your mixin or the call. It should work depending on what the contents of `.flex` are. If I add some dummy properties, it does work in the latest Less compiler (v2.5.3).

Comment: maybe you find this useful: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1177

Comment: @Harry I added a full example, it fails to add .body > main to flex declaration.

Comment: Does it work for you? That example?

Comment: @momo: Yes, in the official Less compiler (v2.5.3) it does extend and apply the `color` to `body > main` also. I don't know which version of compiler is used by the Java port though. You may want to check that up.

Comment: Hmm good to know. I am cofused by the version numbers. My java version is using 1.7.5, but the current version is 2.5.3 ? How is that possible in a year? Have they jumped or is my java version using some customized other version?